# Jenkins headless browser problem for robot class implementation

Tags: java, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, headless-browser

I'm trying to automate file download using i.e browser where i have used robot class to deal with download pop up. This works fine for the local machine but when i run the same script on jenkins which has a headless browser my script always fails. What could be the better solution to deal with this?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that by robot you mean `java.awt.Robot` than unfortunately it doesn't support headless mode. As per [`Robot()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html#%3Cinit%3E()) constructor javadoc:

```
AWTException - if the platform configuration does not allow low-level 
               input control. This exception is always thrown when
               GraphicsEnvironment.isHeadless() returns true
```

Either stop using `java.awt.Robot` or stop using headless environment.

Comment: Hi Karol, thanks for writing this answer. I cannot stop using headless environment. Can you please suggest a way out of it ??

Comment: Is this still true as in 2022?